# Eslint: Possible race condition when calling MongoDB db function

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've got some code that is calling the MongoDB db function but I'm getting a eslint warning -> `` Possible race condition: `testUtilsData.mongoDB` might be reassigned based on an outdated value of `testUtilsData.mongoDB`.eslintrequire-atomic-updates ``

The code is:

```
//Set up Mongo DB connection
const __initDB = async () => {
  testUtilsData.mongoConnection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__);
  testUtilsData.mongoDB = await testUtilsData.mongoConnection.db('test');
};
```

where testUtilsData is defined outside the function -> `const testUtilsData = {};`. Unfortunately I can't just disable the rule.

Any ideas? Many thanks.